# Is past perfect most appropriate here?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect

Which sentence is correct?

It was very easy for us to adjust to our new home because we were already used to living in a big city.

It was very easy for us to adjust to our new home because we had already been used to living in a big city.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It would depend on context, whether the condition of living in a big city were still the case. It is was ongoing, then it would be the first. If it was a past condition that had ceased, then it would be the second.

Comment: They're both "correct", but in practice most native speakers wouldn't bother with the more complex past perfect form. Particularly when it's bound up with ***to be used to***, which is already a "complex" verb form, so you're really just piling up unnecessary syntactic baggage for no semantic advantage. I don't think there's anything in the distinction @Nigel makes above.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the second sentence is correct, because "already" is one of the markers of the present perfect and the past perfect.